# the google charts example "Populating Data Using Server-Side Code " is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to use Google charts with json file data, but until the google doc example is not working for me... i got the error

> table has no columns

the codes are exactly equals the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php 

// This is just an example of reading server side data and sending it to the client.
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.

$string = file_get_contents("sampleData.json");
echo $string;

// Instead you can query your database and parse into JSON etc etc

?>
```

```
{
    "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Im having the same issue. Were you able to get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didn' get json .you can console.log(jsonData) to see it .

if it is undefined,you should check you ajax  code .
I suggest you to use $.getJSON() to get json data

if it is a string ,you should json.parse it.